# create a custom table like Foo table in android using Java

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create something like Foo table to display the large table. Can Any one tell how to create table layout like foo table in android native app.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ExpandableListView`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: yes kind of but is there any plugins to make the work easy with pagination.